# Parse shortcodes from another site in WP Multisite

Tags: multisite, shortcode

I'm retrieving a list of posts from various sites in a multisite installation using the following method:

```
$posts = lc_main_eh_posts();

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post);

    if ( $post->blog_id == get_current_blog_id() ) {
        get_template_part('list-medium', get_post_format());
    } else {
        get_template_part('list-medium_auxblog', get_post_format());
    }
}
```

Where `lc_main_eh_posts()` retrieves the posts from all sites using `WP_Query` and  `switch_to_blog()` and returns an ordered array of `WP_Post`s. It also assigns the blog id each post belongs to in `$post->blog_id` for later use.

In `list-medium_auxblog.php`, I'm doing:

```
<p>
    <?php

    $content = strip_tags(strip_shortcodes(get_the_content()));
    $trimmed_content = wp_trim_words($content, 20, '...');

    echo $trimmed_content;

    ?>
</p>
```

The problem arises when there's a shortcode in use in a post that belongs to a different blog/site. I've tried `apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content)`, `do_shortcode(get_the_content())`, and `strip_shortcodes()` is in use there and it doesn't even work. The shortcodes just appear as raw text.

I also tried adding `switch_to_blog()` and `restore_current_blog()` before and after the template tags shown above, with no luck.

I suspect this is due to the fact that those shortcodes are not registered network-wide. I can't just enable them, because they display data that is only in the database of specific sites.

What other options do I have? How can I parse shortcodes from posts that belong to other sites in the MS as if the current blog was that one ?

Comment: Are you trying to strip specific shortcodes from `the_content`, or do you want to remove everything that's in `[square_brackets]`?

Comment: No, I want to *display*/*render* shortcodes from other sites

Comment: Per the [`switch_to_blog()` documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog), plugins *are not* switched in a `switch_to_blog()` call. So you'd need to have the shortcode's plugins active on your origin site.